# dataframe filtering row by multiple columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
self._df[(self._df.OC_1 != 0) | (self._df.OC_2 != 0) |
                                (self._df.OC_3 != 0) |
                                (self._df.OC_4 != 0) |
                                (self._df.OC_5 != 0) ]
```

I am wondering what is a better way to write this piece of code: can I use a list that contains the name of the column, or something like that?

Comment: cols = ['b','c']
df[df[cols].any(axis=1)]

Answer (score 1):

```
cols = ['b','c']
df[df[cols].any(axis=1)]
```

This would work.